# Days to live of a population where everyone has a 50% chance to produce 2 offsprings

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider a population of day flies. Each one lives at most one day.
On each day and for each living day fly there is a 50% chance to produce 2 offsprings (on its own).

Start with one day fly.

```
 n | p(n)
   | Chance the population lasts exactly n days
---+------------------------
 1 | 0.5
   | [if the first fly dies without producing offsprings]
   |
 2 | 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5
   | [if the first fly produces offsprings
   |  and then both die without producing offsprings on the next day]
   |
 n | ?
```

Even for $n=3$ this is considerably more complicated:

1. The first fly needs to produce offspring.
2. The first of its offspring must produce offspring, which both need to die, and the second of its offspring must die or produce offspring which both die as well or vice versa.

Is there a closed formula for $p(n)$?

Its clear that:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty p(n) = 1 \implies p(n) \rightarrow 0
$$
How does the distribution look like?

What is the average number of days the population lives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the generating function $g_n(s)=E(s^{Z_n})$ of the number $Z_n$ of living individuals at time $n$. Then $Z_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{Z_n}L_{k,n}$ where $L_{k,n}$ denotes the offspring of the $k$th individual living at time $n$. Thus $(L_{k,n})$ is i.i.d. and distributed like $L$, where $E(s^L)=u(s)$ with $u(s)=\frac12(1+s^2)$, and
$$
g_{n+1}(s)=E\left(E(s^L)^{Z_n}\right)=g_n(u(s)),
$$
hence $g_n(s)=g_0(u_n(s))$ where $u_{n+1}(s)=u(u_n(s))=u_n(u(s))$ with $u_0(s)=s$.

In particular, starting from one individual, one gets $g_0(s)=s$ hence
$$
\sum_{k\leqslant n}p_k=P[Z_n=0]=g_n(0)=u_n(0).
$$
Unfortunately, iterating quadratic functions is notoriously difficult. Fortunately, estimating $u_n(0)$ is rather straightforward, leading to $1-u_n(0)\sim\frac2n$ and 
$$
p_n\sim\frac2{n^2}.
$$
It follows that the average life $\sum\limits_nnp_n$ of the population starting from one individual is infinite while the population dies after an almost surely finite number of days.